# What is the <> operator in Chisel?

Tags: scala, chisel

The Chisel tutorials make use of what appears to be a `<>` operator, which is completely unfamiliar to me. What does it do?

Also, where does it come from? Is there a conventional meaning for this operator in other Scala libraries or even other languages?

Here is an example usage, from the the Chisel Generator Bootcamp exercises, section 3.2:

```
class MyQueue extends Module {
    // Example circuit using a Queue
    val io = IO(new Bundle {
        val in = Flipped(Decoupled(UInt(8.W)))
        val out = Decoupled(UInt(8.W))
    })
    val queue = Queue(io.in, 2)  // 2-element queue
    io.out <> queue
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<>` is used to bulk connect all of the identically named ports between two modules. So in the example above,

```
io.out <> queue
```

is a more concise way to write

```
io.out.valid := queue.valid
io.out.bits := queue.bits
queue.ready := io.out.ready
```

since they are both wrapped by the `Decoupled` interface, which defines `ready`, `valid` and `bits` ports (note that the `ready` connection flows in the opposite direction: bulk connect handles this correctly).

I found [the answer](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/wiki/Interfaces-Bulk-Connections#bulk-connections) after reading the Chisel wiki more thoroughly.

Comment: One minor modification to this answer, your expanded form is correct except that the direction of `ready` is opposite that of `valid` and `bits`, so it really should be `queue.ready := io.out.ready`. An important feature of `<>` is its handling of bidirectional types like DecoupledIO

Comment: Thank you! I've made an edit to reflect your correction

Answer (score 2):

In Scala, most symbols like /!<> etc. are valid method name. It is case by case what the operator/method is defined.

The method call can also have a different syntax which you can replace `.()` with spaces e.g.

```
a.foo(bar)
```

is the same as

```
a foo bar
```

So the operator call:

```
a <> b
```

is the same as

```
a.<>(b)
```

Comment: Right, perhaps I should clarify: I'm asking what `<>` does in Chisel, and also what its "etymology" is, if there is any.

Comment: @alcorn Check out the documentation