# chisel partial bulk connection with "<>" operator

Tags: chisel

I'm having trouble to do partial bulk connection with <>.
I saw in the book [Digital Design with Chisel](https://github.com/schoeberl/chisel-book/wiki/chisel-book.pdf) (4.3 Bulk Connections).
It is allowed to connect two bundles with partially matched signals.

I'm currently working on chisel3.2. and it seems not working, and during elatorating it
reports 
`chisel3.internal.ChiselException: Connection between left (AnonymousBundle(IO io in Fetch)) and source (AnonymousBundle(IO io in Decode)) failed @.regB: Left Record missing field (regB).`

Is this changed at some version?

If it is changed, how do we do partial connection now?

This is the testing code(don't mind the module, it is only to keep the signal from optimization):

```scala
class Fetch extends Module {
val io = IO(new Bundle {
val instr = Output(UInt(32.W))
val pc = Output(UInt(32.W))
})
  val r = RegInit(0.U(32.W))
  r := r + 1.U
  io.pc := r
  io.instr := r+1.U
}
class Decode extends Module {
val io = IO(new Bundle {
val instr = Input(UInt(32.W))
val pc = Input(UInt(32.W))
val aluOp = Output(UInt(5.W))
val regA = Output(UInt(32.W))
val regB = Output(UInt(32.W))
})
  io.aluOp := io.pc
  io.regA := io.instr
  io.regB := io.instr
}
class Execute extends Module {
val io = IO(new Bundle {
val aluOp = Input(UInt(5.W))
val regA = Input(UInt(32.W))
val regB = Input(UInt(32.W))
val result = Output(UInt(32.W))
})
 io.result := io.regA
  when(io.aluOp > 10.U){
    io.result := io.regB
  }
}
```

```scala
object MAIN{
 def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
    Driver.execute(Array(""),()=>new Module{
      val io = IO(new Bundle{
        val result = Output(UInt(32.W))
      })
      val fetch = Module(new Fetch())
      val decode = Module(new Decode())
      val execute = Module(new Execute)
      fetch.io <> decode.io
      decode.io <> execute.io
      io <> execute.io
    })
 }
}
```

Comment: I would like to give a more detailed answer with options to solve but don't have time at the moment. In short, this was removed intentionally. Over the years of hardware design with Chisel, we found that the number 1 cause of hard-to-debug bugs was when we'd refactor a block, add a field to a Bundle, and then some other user of that block would not know about the addition and would have Verilog that doesn't work. Keep an eye on https://github.com/freechipsproject/www.chisel-lang.org/pull/48 where I am working on documentation around the differences and migration strategies.

Comment: The way we write code to not need this feature is via composition. If you have fields in one Bundle that you want to connect to the same fields in another Bundle, it's usually best to create a new Bundle that contains those fields and instantiate the new Bundle in each of the others. Then you can just connect the subfield.

Comment: @JackKoenig Hi, maybe you can elaborate on the `composition` method? How do we do   a workaround for such circumstances if we still want to connect the corresponding ports of `fetch` & `decode`, `decode` & `exe`, `exe` & `io` together?

Answer (score 0):

Link:[chisel3-vs-chisel2](https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/docs/appendix/chisel3-vs-chisel2.html)

> In Unsupported constructs Chapter:
>
> - In Chisel2, bulk-connects <> with unconnected source components do not update connections from the unconnected components.
> - In Chisel3, bulk-connects strictly adhere to last connection semantics and unconnected OUTPUTs will be connected to INPUTs resulting in the assignment of random values to those inputs.

I'm sorry that I have not fully understanded how to use <> in Chisel3.In my opinion, you should avoid to use <> in Chisel3.

Here is an example that is avaiable in Chisel3.

> Code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52123791/what-is-the-operator-in-chisel).

```
import Chisel.Queue
import chisel3._
import chisel3.stage.{ChiselGeneratorAnnotation, ChiselStage}
import chisel3.util.Decoupled
import layered.stage.ElkStage

class MyQueue extends Module {
    // Example circuit using a Queue
    val io = IO(new Bundle {
        val in = Flipped(Decoupled(UInt(8.W)))
        val out = Decoupled(UInt(8.W))
    })
    val queue = Queue(io.in, 2)  // 2-element queue
    io.out <> queue
}

object MyQueue extends App{
    (new ChiselStage).emitVerilog(new MyQueue,Array("-td", "vout"))
    
    // gengerate graph file and it can be viewed by using IDEA plugin named EasySocHDL
    (new ElkStage).execute(
        Array("-td", "vout", "--lowFir"),
        Seq(ChiselGeneratorAnnotation(() => new MyQueue))
    )
}
```